# Need to read a CSV file using Azure Data Factory Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file. 
I need to read each row and access the column values and for each row I need to call a foreach activity.

With what activity can I achieve this?

Comment: @ASH sorry I am new to ADF.. couldn't figure it out with google.
Also I don't want to copy the csv. I need to access the values inside it row by row and call a foreach activity for each row.

Comment: Row by row?  I don't think that makes sense.  What is your end game here?

Comment: csv file has 2 columns.. for each row I need to create a folder structure such as this column1/column2/

Comment: Sorry, again, this makes no sense.  You manage data to answer a question or solve a problem.  I don't see a problem or question here.  I don't think I can help you, but good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the CSV file is in a cloud storage , you can use the lookup activity . Please beware that lookup activity has a limitation of 5000 at this time . Once you have done that you can use a FE loop and iterate through it .
Hope this helps